# Logstash doesn't replace variables in http output plugin

Tags: logging, logstash

I am trying to setup a logstash pipeline that outputs logs to differents other logstash instances based on the field `[logstash_url]` in my log :

```
http {
    url => "http://%{[logstash_url]}:5044"
    retry_failed => 'false'
    http_method => 'post'
    retry_non_idempotent => 'true'
    format => 'json_batch'
    http_compression => 'true'
}
```

The problem is that logstash doesn't replace `[logstash_url]` and I get the following trace:

```
[ERROR] 2022-11-16 14:20:04.014 [[main]>worker0] http - Could not fetch URL {:url=>"http://%{[logstash_url]}:5044", :method=>:post, :message=>"Malformed escape pair at index 16: http://%{[logstash_url]}:5044", :class=>"Java::JavaNet::URISyntaxException", :will_retry=>false}
```

The field `[logstash_url]` does exist and I can even use it in filter or other output types.

The image I am using is `docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:8.1.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was the `format => 'json_batch'`  option that was causing the issue.
I removed it and the `[logstash_url]` is now correctly replaced and logs are forwarded to the appropriate logstash instances.